# How does Django find template?

Tags: python, django

Below is my urls.py in `mysite/mysite/settings.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='homepage/main.html')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), # add something
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('hello/', include('hello.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),  # Add, Search how does djnago find template.
    path('autos/', include('autos.urls')),
]
```

If some user request [www.mysite.com/accounts/login](http://www.mysite.com/accounts/login)

This request go to `'django.contrib.auth.urls'` in there request go to `path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login')` not in ﻿django/contrib/auth/urls.py..

But my login template is in `mysite/homepage/templates/registration/login.html`
And below is my `login.html`

```
{% extends "base_bootstrap.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
  <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

It works well. so I don't know how Django find my `login.html`

How does Django find my `login.html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has two main ways it will look for templates, defined the settings. I'll show an example.

```py
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent + '/'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'website',
    'users',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR + 'templates',
            '/var/my_other_templates',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

In this example, let's say we are using a `TemplateView` with the attribute `template_name = 'users/login.html'`, or `{% include "users/login.html" %}` in a template. Either way, the search will be the same.

- The first is through the list of directories provided in `DIRS`, which it will check in order. If it finds a file called `login.html` at `./templates/users/login.html`, it will use that template and stop looking. Otherwise, it will look for `/var/my_other_templates/users/login.html`.
- If it doesn't find the template in either location, it will move on to your apps. First, it will look in `./website/templates/users/login.html`, and failing that, `./users/templates/users/login.html`.

If it doesn't find the template in any of those locations in this example, it will return a `TemplateNotFound` error, and the error will show all the directories in which Django looked for the template.

If you're using Django's internal apps, it will pull the templates from those apps if you haven't overridden them.